# What is an intent-filter than would only show an app in the share menu when sharing a url?

Tags: android, url, share, intentfilter

I have looked at the intent-filter documentation and I can't figure out this specific intent-filter.

I'm looking to use ACTION_SEND because I only want the app to show up in "Share" menus in other apps.  I only want to show up in the share menu if the text of the intent is a url.  For example, what is shared from the Android Browser's share menu.  I don't want the app to appear in the share menu if it's just text and not a url.

What I have so far is:

```
<intent-filter android:label="Label">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, this will receive any text, not just urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can create [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) objects programmatically, and they can filter on URI schema among other things... much more control.</strike>

I thought subclassing IntentFilter would give you event more, but they made all the variations on "match" `final` so you can't override them in a subclass.  Bah!

[Eurika!](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

You can specify a data "scheme" instead of a mimetype.  Just ask for "http" and "https" (in separate intent filters?).

```
<intent-filter>
  ...
  <data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look through this.  If I create it programmatically will it work even when the app is not running?

Comment: I looked through that link and am unsure of how it would work to subclass the IntentFilter.  Do you have any links that give some examples?  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I haven't the foggiest idea... and without the ability to rewrite "match" I'm not sure there's a point to doing so.  Besides you should be able to set all the available attributes via the Manifest, so I'm not so sure my suggestion is all that helpful.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The problem is that the url comes from the shared app as a string extra.  The android:scheme doesn't appear to apply to extras, it seems to apply to the data passed to the intent.  I think that would work for an intent like ACTION_VIEW but maybe not ACTION_SEND?